# Denominator in Bayes - in the continuous case, why isn't it zero?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

For a continuous random variable, the probability of any particular value is zero. Only by integrating over some range is a non-zero probability obtained.

The components of the Bayes theorem are random variables.

Thus, in the case of Bayes written for **continuous** data, 
say D is the height mass of something, why isn't the dedenominator $P(D)$ zero?  The probability density of any particular value is zero (yes)?

$$  
  P(M|D) = \frac{ P(D|M) P(M) }{ P(D) }
$$

I believe that in the Bayes formula we can assign D as the value of a single observation OR as a collection of observations (yes?).  If so, in the case where the collection is a continuous interval, then $P(D)$ would be non-zero.

I am also aware that $P(D) = \int P(D|M) P(M) \, dM$.  *However this does not answer the question for me.* Again consider the case where the data is the mass (or height).  You can measure a particular mass, but the probability of that exact mass is zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $D$ is a continuous random variable, the expression $P(D)$ refers to the probability *density* of $D$, instead of the probability mass.

Comment: Right, but that is the source of the problejm (I believe). The probability density for a single value from a continuous distribution is zero.

Am I wrong?

Comment: please distinguish probability mass from "mass" in the question. I am using mass (related to weight) as an example of a continuous quantity.

Comment: @basicidea "The probability density for a single value from a continuous distribution is $0$." No, that's not correct. The key word here is *density*. For example, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, the probability density of $X$ at $1/3$ is equal to $1$.